# Is there any way to make the default language of a program programmatically determinable?

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

for a project of mine it is necessary to make the default language of a Java client programmatically determinable. That means, a screen reader software should be able to get the language so that it reads in the associated pronunciation. In HTML it's done with the lang attribute, is there something similar in Java?
And if so, is there any way to determine the language for just a sentence?

Comment: You could try setting the default `Locale`, but I honestly don't know how that affects a screen reader, if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default `Locale`, i.e. `Locale.setDefault(Locale newLocale)`.